# displaytag : Needs to send POST request rather than GET

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

I am using DisplayTag 1.1, using server side pagination/sorting (partialList=true). But I am not finding any documentation to make POST request rather than GET request for "next page" or "First/Last" page link is clicked. The code is standard such as

```
<display:table name="testList" sort="external" defaultsort="1" pagesize="20" id="element" partialList="true" size="resultSize">
  <display:column property="id" title="ID" sortable="true" sortName="id" />
  <display:column property="firstName" sortable="true" sortName="firstName" title="First Name" />
  <display:column property="lastName" sortable="true" sortName="lastName" title="Last Name" />
  <display:column property="address" sortable="true" sortName="address" title="Email Address"/>
</display:table>
```

All the pagination links are done using GET method, need POST method.

Answer (score 0):

There is "form" attribute on  tab to make it POST request. But the problem was 1.1 version does not support "form" attribute and there is a documentation error that mentions it under 1.1 . 
I changed my displaytag version to 1.2 (with some hiccups) and then POST worked.